# Kendo UI - Displaying notification in requestEnd

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Greeting All,

On Kendo Grid [requestEnd](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/requestend) is that possible if I call [kendo notification](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/notification/templates) when successful updating record?

In [this Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OrUGiguY) I try to implement it, but somehow after I updated to record it keep buffering and not displaying the notification.

Can someone help me to solve this problem? 
Thank you in advance!

I include the function just in case:

```
function KendoAlert(content) {
  $("<div></div>").kendoAlert({
    title: "Messages!",
    content: content
  }).data("kendoAlert").open();
}   

function KendoNotify(message) {
  notification.show({
     message: message
  }, "upload-success");
}

function onRequestEnd(e) {
  debugger;

  if (e.type == "update" && !e.response.Errors) {
    KendoNotify("Update Done!");
    //KendoAlert("Update Done!");
  }  
}
```

[Demo In Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OrUGiguY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are specifying the variable `notification` within `$(document).ready`. Once the function finishes, the variable `notification` is lost (read https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/4944034 for more information about the scope of a variable)

I did a minor change to your example and got a notification:

```
var notification;
$(document).ready(function () {
  notification = $("#notification").kendoNotification({
```

Comment: ouch! I didn't see that coming. Thank you for notify me about that, i'll take noted after this.

Comment: Don't forget: you can accept this answer if it was the correct or useful solution. Read more about accepting answers on https://stackoverflow.com/tour